# range / interval query algorithm

Tags: algorithms, hash, searching

I've an hash (base 32 for what it's worth):

```
hash = 'ab352eghjhngd4'
```

And I've subscribers that want to listen to new hashes in a **range**.

```
   listener = { startAt: 'ab31', endAt: 'ab40', obj }  
   listener2 = { startAt: 'ab350', endAt: 'ab351', obj }
```

In this case `listener1` should be notified of the new hash while `listener2` shouldn't.

I'd like to find another algorithm than just iterating through all listeners to find if they fit.

---

I was thinking of holding an array for `startAt`

```
startAtOrderedArray = [
       { startAt: 'ab31', endAt: 'ab40', obj }, 
       { startAt: 'ab350', endAt: 'ab351', obj },
       { startAt: 'uc', endAt: 'uc2', obj }
    ]
```

Then using binary search I can forget the third item because it's above the hash which was `ab352eghjhngd4`.

Then I can do the same with `endAt`.

```
endAtOrderedArray = [
       { startAt: 'uc', endAt: 'uc2', obj },
       { startAt: 'ab31', endAt: 'ab40', obj }, 
       { startAt: 'ab350', endAt: 'ab351', obj },
    ]
```

So I end up with:

```
 before = [
           { startAt: 'ab31', endAt: 'ab40', obj }, 
           { startAt: 'ab350', endAt: 'ab351', obj },
        ]

 after = [
           { startAt: 'uc', endAt: 'uc2', obj },
           { startAt: 'ab31', endAt: 'ab40', obj }, 
        ]
```

So now if an item is in both array then it's interested in the hash.

The issue however is the complexity is still linear so I'm wondering how can I do better ?

---

*I'd like the question to be as general as possible but for my specific use case it is likely that the first char of `startAt` and `endAt` are the same. So `{ startAt: 'ab', endAt: 'u23' }` is not likely.*

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).  It is designed to support exactly this. In particular, the query "find all ranges that contain this value" is known as a stabbing query, and it can be answered in essentially $O(\log n)$ time.